# Excel file has bigger size using OPENQUERY to update it

Tags: sql-server, excel

Maybe the solution can be so easy but I can't find it so I write here for some help.

We have this sql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[updateExcel]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @cell VARCHAR(4),
    @description VARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)              
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE openquery(LinkedServer2ExcelFile, ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$'+@cell+':'+@cell+']'') set F1 = '''+@description+''''           
    --PRINT @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    RETURN 0

END
```

that we use to update some excel file

```
EXEC @Result = updateExcel 'somecell', 'somevalue'
```

The problem is that after this update the excel has a bigger size. But when we open it and save it again, the file's size get normal again

I hope to find here some answers ...

Thanx !!!